# How to show a WPF window from a public static method in a Class Library project (dll)

Tags: wpf, dll

I want to use WPF windows in future applications instead of Windows forms.

The current setup is as Class Library Project with a public static method. I have added a Windows Form item to the Project. In the public static method I create an instance of the Windows Form Class and use the method ShowDialog.

The reason why I use this setup is that I need my own .net dialog in an other program. This program can only call public static methods i .net.

I have solved the problem by creating a WPF Application Project and added a public Class item to this project. In the public static method i create an instace of the WPF window class and use the method ShowDialog. This works but I would like to create a dll without main-method.

How to show a WPF window from a public static method in a Class Library project (dll)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Class library projects don't have the WPF Window template, so you need to create a UserControl and then change the main tag from `<UserControl ...>` to `<Window ...>`. Alternatively, you can create the Window in a WPF application project and then copy the `MyWindow.xaml*` files to your library project. (In that case, you might need to fix the `Build Action` property of the Window in the property window. Visual Studio seems to mess that up when copying a XAML file into a non-WPF class library.)

Afterwards, you can show it like you would in an application: In your static method, you create an instance of your Window and call `ShowDialog`.